# How can I execute MySQL commands line by line from bash and capture the output?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

If there is an alternative to bash, I will appreciate it too.

I have a large dump of MySQL commands (over 10 GB)

When restoring the dump I get a few warnings and occasionally an error. I need to execute those commands and process all warnings and errors. And, preferibly to do it automatically.

```sql
mysql --show-warnings
tee logfile.log
source dump.sql
```

The logfile will contain many lines telling each command was successful, and will display some warnings, particulartly truncate colums. But the original file has tens of thousands of very large `INSERT`s, the log is not particularly helpful. Despite it requires some kind of supervised interaction. (I cannot program a `crontab`, for example.)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "tee logfile.log" > script.sql
echo "source $1" > script.sql
mysql --show-warnings < script.sql > tmpfile.log 2>&1
cat tmpfile.log >> logfile.log
```

The `tee` command doesn't work in this batch environment. I can capture all the warnings, but I cannot figure out which command produced each warning.

So I came down with this small monstruosity:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ERRFILE=$(basename "$0" .sh).err.log
LOGFILE=$(basename "$1" .sql).log
log_action() {
    WARN=$(cat)
    [ -z "$WARN" ] || echo -e "Line ${1}: ${WARN}\n${2}" >> "$LOGFILE"
}
echo 0 > "$ERRFILE"
log_error() {
    ERNO=$(cat "$ERRFILE")
    ERR=$(cat)
    [ -z "$ERR" ] || echo -e "*** ERROR ***\nLine ${1}: ${ERR}\n${2}" >> "$LOGFILE"
    (( ERNO++ ))
    echo $ERNO > "$ERRFILE"
}
COUNT=0
COMMAND=''
echo -e "**** BEGIN $(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S)\n" > "$LOGFILE"
exec 4> >(log_action $COUNT "$COMMAND")
exec 5> >(log_error $COUNT "$COMMAND")
exec 3> >(mysql --show-warnings >&4 2>&5)
while IFS='' read -r LINE || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    (( COUNT++ ))
    [ ${#LINE} -eq 0 ] && continue          # discard blank lines
    [ "${LINE:0:2}" = "--" ] && continue    # discard comments
    COMMAND+="$LINE"                        # build command
    [ "${LINE: -1}" != ";" ] && continue    # if not finnished keep building
    echo $COMMAND >&3                       # otherwise execute
    COMMAND=''
done < "$1"
exec 3>$-
exec 5>$-
exec 4>$-
echo -e "**** END $(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S)\n" >> "$LOGFILE"
ERRS=$(cat "$ERRFILE")
[ "ERRS" = 0 ] || echo "${ERRS} Errors." >&2
```

This scans the file at `$1` and sends the commands to an open MySQL connection at &3. That part is working fine.

The capture of warnings and errors is not working though.

1. It only records the first error.
2. It only records the first warning.
3. I haven't find a good way to pass the line number `$COUNT` and offending command `$COMMAND` to the recording functions.
4. The only error is after the time stamps, and the only warning is after the error, which is not the chronology of the script.